# Adding Multiple View Params to a Lightning Button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute

I'd like to disable a Lightning button under certain conditions.

```
<aura:attribute name="showSecurityComponent" type="Boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="checkCaptcha" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
<aura:attribute name="removeUserDisableButtons" type="Boolean" />
```

The intent is to disable the button if 1) both `showSecurityComponent` and `checkCaptcha` are true, 2) or if `removeUserDisableButtons` is true.

I'm passing all three value params inside the `disabled` property of the button:

```
<lightning:button aura:id="saveButtonEdit"
                  variant="brand"
                  label="Save and continue"
                  onclick="{! c.saveEditClick}"
                  disabled="{!and(v.checkCaptcha,v.showSecurityComponent,v.removeUserDisableButtons)}" />
```

But this isn't disabling the buttons. I'm not sure what's wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try this?

```
<lightning:button aura:id="saveButtonEdit"
                  variant="brand"
                  label="Save and continue"
                  onclick="{! c.saveEditClick}"
                  disabled="{!or(and(v.checkCaptcha,v.showSecurityComponent),v.removeUserDisableButtons))}
```

Comment: Thanks, `{!or(and(v.checkCaptcha,v.showSecurityComponent),v.removeUserDisableButtons)}` works exactly how I hoped. Need to read up on the `and` / `or` syntax.